# How to recode a variable programmatically using quasiquotation?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I have the following dataset and would like to recode the variables

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
mytib <- tribble(~colA, ~colB, ~colC,
        "good", "bad", "better",
        "better", "bad", "worse",
        "good", "best", "good")
```

In my dataset, I have tons more columns so I am looking for a programmatic approach to recoding the dataset so that "bad" and "worse" are collapsed into "terrible" and "good", "better", "best" are collapse into "awesome". All of this should be coded into new columns, one for each variable like "colA_bin" (for binary), "colB_bin", and "colC_bin". Since I have many columns I would like to do this using the `dplyr::select(starts_with(...) & ends_with(...))` functions.

What I have come up with is the following:

```
attractiveness_vars <- mytib %>%
                             dplyr::select(starts_with(c("col")) & ends_with(c("A", "B", "C")) %>%
                             names(.)
attractiveness_lvls_neg <- c("bad", "worse")
attractiveness_lvls_pos <- c("good", "better", "best")
attractiveness_lvls_new <- c("terrible", "awesome")

recode_attractiveness <- function(dataframe, column_name, lvls_neg, lvls_pos, lvls_new){
    new_col <- dataframe %>%
    mutate({{column_name}} := factor(case_when({{column_name}} %in% 
                                                                 lvls_neg ~ lvls_new[1],
                                                               {{column_name}} %in%
                                                                 lvls_pos ~ lvls_new[2],
                                                               TRUE ~ NA_character_),
                                                     levels = lvls_new)) %>%
    pull({{column_name}})
    return(new_col)
}
```

When I run

```
recode_attractiveness(mytib, attractiveness_vars, attractiveness_lvls_neg, attractiveness_lvls_pos, attractiveness_lvls_new)
```

I receive an error `` ℹ Input `attractiveness_vars` must be size [NROW] or 1, not [length(attractiveness_vars)]. `` Note, it actually tells me the numbers, I've just tried to make it easier to read.

There's probably an easier way to approach this. I'd love to know if there is a quasiquotation way to solve this problem or (regardless of whether there is or isn't) an elegant programmatic solution, i.e. one that doesn't involve me typing out the case_when(...) code.

The expected output should look like this

```
colA   colA_bin  colB  colB_bin   colC     colC_bin
"good" "awesome" "bad" "terrible" "better" "awesome"
...
```

Comment: Could you clarify what your expected output is?

Comment: `starts_with` or `ends_with` takes a single elemnt.  May be you need `matches` `mytib %>% select(matches('^col.*[ABC]$'))`.  Also, the `{{}}` is looking for unquoted column names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe skip the function definition all together and use `across`?

```
library(dplyr) # Version >= 1.0.0
mytib %>% 
  mutate(across(one_of(attractiveness_vars),
                ~ factor(case_when(. %in% attractiveness_lvls_neg ~ attractiveness_lvls_new[1],
                                   . %in% attractiveness_lvls_pos ~ attractiveness_lvls_new[2],
                                   TRUE ~ NA_character_),
                         levels = attractiveness_lvls_new),
                .names = "{col}_bin"))
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  colA   colB  colC   colA_bin colB_bin colC_bin
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <fct>    <fct>    <fct>   
1 good   bad   better awesome  terrible awesome 
2 better bad   worse  awesome  terrible terrible
3 good   best  good   awesome  awesome  awesome
```

For bonus points, you might use `forcats::fct_collapse`:

```
library(forcats)
attractiveness_factors <- setNames(list(attractiveness_lvls_neg, attractiveness_lvls_pos),
                                   attractiveness_lvls_new)
attractiveness_factors
#$terrible
#[1] "bad"   "worse"
#$awesome
#[1] "good"   "better" "best"  

mytib %>% 
  mutate(across(one_of(attractiveness_vars),
                ~ fct_collapse(.,!!!attractiveness_factors),
                .names = "{col}_bin"))
```

Comment: Could you explain what the ```{col}_bin``` does? Also, is there a way to use .relocate to change the ordering in this one function call?

Comment: From `help(across)` section `.names`: "A glue specification that describes how to name the output columns. This can use `{.col}` to stand for the selected column name, and `{.fn}` to stand for the name of the function being applied. The default (NULL) is equivalent to `"{.col}"` for the single function case and `"{.col}_{.fn}"` for the case where a list is used for .fns." Which apparently means the more correct version would be `"{.col}_bin"`.

Comment: @TeaTree for the ordering you could use `%>% select(sort(current_vars()))`

Comment: That seems to also change the location of the other variables. Is there an easy way to just put the variables after each of the ones we have just created?

Comment: @TeaTree I'm not aware of an easy way to place the new columns directly to the right of the old columns. Something like `relocate(sort(c(attractiveness_vars, paste0(attractiveness_vars,"_bin"))))` will get them next to each other but they will be moved to the end.